# Should I tell my boss I have a full time job offer?

Tags: new-job, job-offer, ethics

I am currently graduating college and finishing up an internship at company x.

I interviewed with a company, Y,  got an offer and I accepted.

The full-time position at Y is supposed to start in October of next year. However I have the option to start as soon as Jan/Feb of next year as I'm an exception (graduating early now rather than May)

I'm meeting with my boss at company X to talk about "after the internship" and I'm confident they're going to offer me a full-time position.

Should I tell my boss I have an offer? Would it be wrong for me to accept full-time at X knowing I'll quit later in the year to go to company Y?

Any other point you can make would be appreciated.

Comment: Why wouldn't you have told Company Y you can start in January? Why even consider waiting until October? Did they give you a written offer for January?

Comment: Until you have a firm start date you shouldn't say anything. All you really have to do is refuse the offer from Company X, that will speak a great deal to your plans, you really have no obligation to Company X has an intern finishing up their internship.  Just be aware that Company Y could withdraw their offer, they are under no obligation, unless of course you have signed something.  You should start sooner rather then later.

Answer (score 3):

> Should I tell my boss I have an offer?

If the topic of the conversation is "after the internship", then certainly you should tell your boss that you have already accepted a job offer, and when you will be joining them. That will avoid any confusion in case you are correct and your boss intends to make you an offer.

> Would it be wrong for me to accept full-time at X knowing I'll quit
>   later in the year to go to company Y?

So you basically want to lie to the company that took you in for an internship, presumably treated you well (otherwise why would you want to accept a job from them?), and make them treat you like someone who will be around for a while when you know that you won't?

For me, that would be very wrong. Perhaps your view of professionalism differs from mine.

If I were your boss and you did that to me, I'd be very angry, and I'd make sure you never worked for me, my company, or for anyone I know. And you'd better be sure that I don't know anyone at your new employer, or they'll be likely to learn how you treat employers.

Is that really how you want to start your professional career?

You indicate that you have already accepted a job offer. For me, acceptance involves giving my word that I'll actually be there. And my word means a lot to me. I know what I'd do, and what I'd advise my family and friends to do.

Comment: I agree he should be honest.  He shouldn't make any decisions about his current comapny until he has a start date with the second company.

Comment: The OP does not actually have an offer yet... how is not disclosing an offer he does not have lying?  And honestly if later in the year the company hits a rough patch and has to lay off the newest hires, are you as that manager going to pay for the OP's salary out of your pocket?  There is no loyalty from the business side either.

Comment: Sorry but you sound really childish @Joe